# Are there Teams API endpoints available to get channel/call info, such as participant lists?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams

I'm just wondering if there is currently a production version API for Microsoft Teams available, specifically to gather retrospective participant info from calls/meetings (after the meeting had ended) from an external app? I'm aware of some Teams endpoints being available in Microsoft Graph, but am not sure to what extent these are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reaching us!

Teams by default generate attendees report and meeting report after completion of meeting call. We can able to see the list of attendees and the report. But at present we don't have any API to fetch list of attendees and their timings.

As this feature is not available at present, could you please raise an [User Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com) if this needs to be consider as a future request.